# How to put values from one dataframe into another dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Input Dataframe looks like this

```
    options text
1   Stem    I am good
2   Option1 Yes
3   Option2 No
4   Option3 Maybe
5   Option4 ok
```

Output dataframe should look like -

```
 Stem   Stem_Value  All_4_Options_Appended
Stem1   I am Good   'Yes','No','Maybe','ok'
```

I have more than million items like this, so was looking for a function kind of thing

Comment: please provide your input/output as reproducible text, not images

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom groupby aggregation with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to generate the common grouper

```
m = df['options'].eq('Stem')

out = (df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum().astype(str).radd('Stem'))
         .agg(All_4_Options_Appended=('text', ','.join))
         .rename_axis('Stems').reset_index()
       )
```

Output (original example):

```
   Stems                             All_4_Options_Appended
0  Stem1  Describe the most expensive option first, and ...
1  Stem2  Describe the most expensive option first, and ...
```

Output (new example):

```
   Stems All_4_Options_Appended
0  Stem1        Yes,No,Maybe,ok
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, But what i wanted was like.."All_4_Options_Appended" Column should have 4 options appended, not The Stem. & Stems Column should have Stem Text. :/

Comment: @r_learner then please edit your question to provide a minimal example (shorter sentences) that is reproducible (=text) and complete, with the full expected output

Comment: Hi mozway Thanks for Suggestion. I have  edited..  Could you pls check

Comment: @r_learner I think you missed my comment on the **reproducible** part, please **no images**, text only!

Answer (score 0):

The main trick here is that after you are able to create `g` which creates a grouping column/series for required rows, you combine all the `text` values in each group as a list. Then you can combine them with a vectorized method `.str.join(' ')`.

**This method should be faster than `.agg` or `.apply` methods (edit) on smaller datasets**

Try the following. (*Step by step - explanation mentioned in comments*) -

```
s = 'Stem'                                            # Start group for string
g = df['options'].eq(s).cumsum()                      # Create groups based cumsum
o = df.groupby(g)['text'].apply(list).str.join(' ')   # Groupby and combine text to list of texts
o = o.reset_index()                                   # Reset index to get group column
o['options'] = s + o['options'].astype(str)           # Prefix column with Stem
o.columns = ['Stems','All_4_options_Appended']        # Change column names
print(o)
```

```
   Stems                             All_4_options_Appended
0  Stem1  It's the beginning of the quarter, and you're ...
1  Stem2  It's the beginning of the quarter, and you're ...
```

---

## Benchmarks

Solution by @Akshay Sehgal

```
%%timeit

s = 'Stem'
g = df['options'].eq(s).cumsum()
o = df.groupby(g)['text'].apply(list).str.join(' ')
o = o.reset_index()
o['options'] = s + o['options'].astype(str)
o.columns = ['Stems','All_4_options_Appended']
o

#686 µs ± 14.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Solution by @Mozway

```
%%timeit

m = df['options'].eq('Stem')

out = (df.groupby(m.cumsum().astype(str).radd('Stem'))
         .agg(All_4_Options_Appended=('text', ';'.join))
         .rename_axis('Stems').reset_index()
       )

out

#1.44 ms ± 8.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

---

## EDIT: Run for your above set -

```
d = {
  'options': ['Stem', 'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3', 'Option4', 'Stem', 'Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3', 'Option4' ],
  'text': ['I am good', 'Yes', 'No', 'Maybe', 'ok', 'Not great', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No',]
 }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


s = 'Stem'
g = df['options'].eq(s).cumsum()
o = df.groupby(g)['text'].apply(list).str.join(' ')
o = o.reset_index()
o['options'] = s + o['options'].astype(str)
o.columns = ['Stems','All_4_options_Appended']
print(o)
```

```
   Stems     All_4_options_Appended
0  Stem1  I am good Yes No Maybe ok
1  Stem2     Not great No No Yes No
```

Based on your expected output, you seem to require each of the strings as an independent. So this version might work for you better.

```
s = 'Stem'
g = df['options'].eq(s).cumsum()
o = df.groupby(g)['text'].apply(list)         #<--- modified here
o = o.reset_index()
o['options'] = s + o['options'].astype(str)
o.columns = ['Stems','All_4_options_Appended']
print(o)
```

```
   Stems           All_4_options_Appended
0  Stem1  [I am good, Yes, No, Maybe, ok]
1  Stem2     [Not great, No, No, Yes, No]
```

Comment: Note that the comparison is biased, for larger datasets the speed is about equal, in this case I think readability counts ;)

Comment: makes sense. readability is definitely the goal with my approach as well!